# Spotting and dealing with water shoots

Tags: pruning, apples

This well established Bramley tree had been left to grow wild for a few years until I pruned it strongly last year.

It's now throwing new growth up like crazy and I'm not sure if these are all water shoots, and if so what I should do with them.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I pruned the tree to a nice goblet shape, removing entire branches as it is tip fruiting. I understand I need to allow some new shoots to replace existing branches over the future years, but it seems all the new growth are these vertical shots and in not sure how to proceed. Clearly the tree is pretty vigorous because these are up to 2 feet long and all new growth this year.